JPA Mapping : Embeddable Composite Key and Mapping issue
My DB Structure is as follows :
Table : product
        prod_id
        ...

Table : product_category
        prod_id
        category_id 
        ...

Product_category has Unique contsraint on (prod_id,category_id)
My JPA Files are as follows :
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<ProductCategoryEntity> productCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}   

@Embeddable
public class ProductCategoryPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "prod_id")
    private ProductEntity product; //Compiler error : 'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Persistence Entity' 
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Integer categoryId;
    
    ...
}   

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_category")
public class ProductCategoryEntity implements Serializable {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductCategoryPK key;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("prod_id")
    private ProductEntity product;
    
    ...
}

In ProductCategoryPK....line : private ProductEntity product;
I get the following error in my editor "Compiler error : 'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Persistence Entity' "
Cant figure out how to map this. Would really appreciate help

Instead of representing product as a reference to the ProductEntity class, you should use a basic type to hold the product identifier.
For example, you can change it to an Integer type if the product identifier is numeric:
@Column(name = "prod_id")
private Integer productId;

So the class will look like:
@Embeddable
public class ProductCategoryPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "prod_id")
    private Integer productId;
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Integer categoryId;
    
    ...
} 

